# How to reset the app icon badge number for messages/notifications back to zero for ALL APPs on Android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

There appears to be a bug (or strange feature) with the number of notifications displayed on the app icon badge on Android: the number display doesn't reset to 0 and increment from there with new messages after all of the messages/notifications have been viewed.  This is a problem apparently experienced by a Very Large number of Android users.  If possible, want to create an app that can clear this number for All Other Apps, not just for the app that I have created.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.
A moment ago I had no unread messages in WhatsApp, Slack, or gmail.  I had also swiped away the visible notifications for each app on the notification screen.  Each app icon displayed no little red notification badge.  Then, I received a single message on WhatsApp.  The app icon then showed the red dot with the number 36 in it, indicating 36 messages.  That number hasn't been at zero or one in months, basically since I bought the device and installed WhatsApp.  This essentially means that the number displayed is worse than useless, it's simply wrong or misleading at best if it corresponds to some remaining number of somethings that I'm not aware of.  The same basic behavior pattern seems to happen with Slack, gmail, and other apps.

There are posts regarding how to reset the badge icon number for one's own app, eg:

[How to reset the Badge app icon number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720259/how-to-reset-the-badge-app-icon-number)

There are also many posts of users asking how to reset the number without programming, using system functionality, eg:

[https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/926172-incorrect-unread-text-message-count-galaxy-s9-app-badge-icon-has-wrong-number.html#:~:text=Try%20going%20to%20Settings%3EApps,and%20see%20if%20that%20helps.&text=Go%20to%20the%20message%20settings,solve%20the%20message%20count%20issue](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/926172-incorrect-unread-text-message-count-galaxy-s9-app-badge-icon-has-wrong-number.html#:%7E:text=Try%20going%20to%20Settings%3EApps,and%20see%20if%20that%20helps.&text=Go%20to%20the%20message%20settings,solve%20the%20message%20count%20issue)

https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-8/879508-google-email-notifications-numbers-wrong-cant-fix.html

It seems to me that it would be helpful to many people to have an app that the user could give adequate permissions to so that the app could reset the badge icon counter back to 0 for all other apps, so that thereafter, for each of the other apps, if the user got a message/notification, they would see a '1' on the icon badge, rather than some other larger number.

Is it possible for an app to do this?  If it isn't possible to reset all apps at once, is it possible to do it for one app other than the app that is doing the resetting, or to do it for a list of individual apps?

What is the required code?

Also, is it possible to do this in some way through the OS, without requiring specialized code?  I tried the methods that people have posted but didn't find one that worked without substantially disrupting the device (eg wiping the home screen).